# How to get enough reputation points so I can comment on an existing question?

Tags: discussion

I want to post a comment on an existing question. Whats the easiest way to get reputation points and level up so I can do this?

This is a very specific question. How many points, does one need to post a comment? How many actions and of what type does this require me to undertake to achieve?

Comment: The easiest way is to write a high-quality answer under a high-quality question. Or to write multiple high-quality answers under some not-so-high-quality questions. Or to write a high-quality question. In general: Just participate. :)

Comment: Why do you want to submit a comment, comments are supposed to be temporary, which means once they are read they should be deleted

Comment: i didn't know they were temporary, that's interesting to know.

Comment: I wanted to contribute to an ongoing discussion occurring in the comments of a question that was important to me. I don't necessarily feel like participating in the toxic, don't do that, why ask that, already asked, not a question, environment that is stack exchange. The barrier to engaging on this platform is a touch ridiculous.

Comment: Could it be you find questions that are important on Stack Overflow because we have a high barrier? As in: over the last 6 to 8 years we found this model works for the type of content we want to curate. What seems ridiculous to you is a success factor when it comes to content. I give you that our on-boarding is either not sufficient or ignored but the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [meta-tag:faq] offer plenty of background, guidance and tips on participating.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You gain reputation by submitting good questions and by posting helpful answers.
Reputation gains:

```
- Your question is voted up: +10
- Your answer is voted up: +10
- Your answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
- Your suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
- If a bounty is awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
```

Comment: What's with the double "`Your answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)`"?

Comment: I see your struggling at the same point as me Kelvian, sorry if this hasn't helped your reputation points.